# Kafka stretched cluster stopped when second DC become down

Tags: apache-kafka

My Kafka version:

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --version
2.4.1 (Commit:c57222ae8cd7866b)
```

My Kafka cluster configuration looks like:

- 6 nodes Kafka cluster
- 6 x Zookeeper i.e. is installed on each node/broker
- 2 DC's, there are 3 nodes in each DC
- rack-awareness feature is enabled on each node:

```
node1 DC1:
broker.id=1
broker.rack=dc1

node2 DC1:
broker.id=2
broker.rack=dc1

node3 DC1:
broker.id=3
broker.rack=dc1

node1 DC2:
broker.id=4
broker.rack=dc2

node2 DC2:
broker.id=5
broker.rack=dc2

node3 DC2:
broker.id=6
broker.rack=dc2
```

When the whole DC2 become down the kafka cluster stopped and node1 from DC1 show errors like this:

```
[2022-03-16 07:38:45,422] INFO Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x40000004f930002, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-03-16 07:38:45,549] INFO Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x200ab15af610000, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-03-16 07:38:45,787] INFO Client successfully logged in. (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
[2022-03-16 07:38:45,787] INFO Client will use DIGEST-MD5 as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2022-03-16 07:38:45,787] INFO Opening socket connection to server dc2kafkabr2/A.B.C.72:2181. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-03-16 07:38:45,788] INFO Socket error occurred: dc2kafkabr2/A.B.C.72:2181: Connection refused (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-03-16 07:38:46,503] INFO Client successfully logged in. (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
[2022-03-16 07:38:46,503] INFO Client will use DIGEST-MD5 as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2022-03-16 07:38:46,503] INFO Opening socket connection to server dc1kafkabr1/A.B.C.68:2181. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-03-16 07:38:46,504] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /A.B.C.68:35796, server: dc1kafkabr1/A.B.C.68:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-03-16 07:38:46,505] INFO Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x40000004f930002, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-03-16 07:38:46,616] INFO Client successfully logged in. (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
[2022-03-16 07:38:46,617] INFO Client will use DIGEST-MD5 as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2022-03-16 07:38:46,617] INFO Opening socket connection to server dc1kafkabr2/A.B.C.69:2181. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-03-16 07:38:46,617] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /A.B.C.68:38936, server: dc1kafkabr2/A.B.C.69:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-03-16 07:38:46,619] INFO Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x200ab15af610000, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-03-16 07:38:46,896] INFO Client successfully logged in. (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
```

However when the Kafka nodes will be stopped normally/humanly in DC2 by systemctl command then Kafka cluster works properly on the nodes in DC1.

The question is why if DC2 is turned off, the Kafka cluster stops working? How to prevent of it? Any idea?

Best Regards,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Dears,

After next tests I know that problem is by side of Zookeeper because when I trun off two brokers in DC2 the Kafka cluster still works. After turn off kafka.service on the last broker in DC2 the Kafka cluster still works. But when I turn off zookeeper.service on the last broker in DC2 the cluster becomes unresponsive.

This is my zookeeper's configuration:

```
cat zookeeper.properties
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/opt/zookeeper/data
#dataLogDir=/var/log/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=3


############## HARDENING #################
authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl

###########################################

server.1=A.B.C.68:2888:3888
server.2=A.B.C.69:2888:3888
server.3=A.B.C.70:2888:3888
server.4=A.B.C.71:2888:3888
server.5=A.B.C.72:2888:3888
server.6=A.B.C.73:2888:3888
```

Any idea what is wrong in this configuration?

Best Regards,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper quorum is not ensure and this is reason.